# Key adapter not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, setfocus

I have created a KeyAdapter class within my JPanel class, and I tried debugging the click using System.out.println(String par1);

However it doesnt seem to work...

Here is the class:

```
package net.ryanshah;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Menu extends JPanel
{
private GameFrame gf;

private Image bg = new ImageIcon("res/bg.png").getImage();

public Menu(final GameFrame parent) {
    this.gf = parent;
    int width = parent.getWidth();
    int height = parent.getHeight();

    setFocusable(true);

    addKeyListener(new MenuOperator());

    setBackground(Color.black);

    setLayout(null);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
}

public class MenuOperator extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            System.out.println("LOL");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? I have set the key handler in the frame as well as setting the frame to be focusable..

Thanks in advance

~RyanS.

Answer (score 2):

### Things not considered right in the code (IMHO) :

- The way you accessing the images in your code. Consider [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html), over using the constructor of `ImageIcon`, as the former will notify you, in case something goes wrong. For more info, please refer, [Loading Image Icon Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230), for more insight.
- `KeyListeners` are for `AWT`, `Swing` on the other hand uses [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).
- Before, setting background on any `JComponent` prefer to first set the `opaque` property of the said `JComponent` to `true`. Since, `opaque` property is usually dependent on `LookAndFeel` used.
- Avoid the use of  `setLayout(null)`, as much as possible. Please walk through the first paragraph of [Absolute Positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for more information :-)
- THe use of `ImageObserver` as already mentioned in the comments.

This blog [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) by @camickr, will again add loads to your knowledge, as to why `KeyListeners` are not considered a better option and why `KeyBindings` is more suited for such needs :-)

Please have a look at this example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestMenu extends JPanel {

    private Image bg;

    public TestMenu() {
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(
                    new URL("http://i.imgur.com/Aoluk8n.gif"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "SPACE key");
        getActionMap().put("SPACE key", keyAction);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    private Action keyAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println("LOL");
        }
    };

    /*
     * Make this a customary habbit to override
     * this method for the JPanel/JComponent,
     * when ever you extend any of the above classes
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        /*
         * Here the last part of the drawImage is the 
         * ImageObserver, here it is a good practise
         * to keep the instance of the JPanel on which
         * we drawing the image to be notified, till the
         * end, till the image loading is not complete
         */
        g2d.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Painting Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestMenu().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: @rshah : Do press `SPACE` and see the literal `LOL` on the `Console` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Setting your panel focusable is not enough - panel cannot get focus on its own - you have to request the focus on some kind of event. For example you can add a mouse listener to your panel and call `panel.requestFocusInWindow()` when you click on it.

Key listener will work **only** if component on which you add it has focus.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If you click on the panel with such focus-transferring mouse listener and try pressing space after - you will see that key listener works.

Comment: So i need a mouse listener too?

Comment: You need focus to be on your panel, not on some button, field or whatever else. Panel cannot just take the focus by itself, even if you set it focusable - you have to pass the focus manually using the method i mentioned. So yes, mouse listener can be an option of manual passing the focus into your panel.